# Logging in locally to Domain controller - Windows AD

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller

After enabling my AD role in my Windows Server 2012 R2 and promoting it as a Domain Controller, I am no longer able to login locally onto the Windows Server itself.

Specifying my `computername\Administrator` or `.\Administrator` doesn't work.

Is it normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you promote a server to a DC, it no longer uses the local account database. This database is only used when you boot your server in Directory Services Recovery Mode (DSRM), which makes the service inoperative as a DC while booted into this mode. This is the password you get to set when running dcpromo.

This is why your local account will not work - there is no local account any more.

Some more good info may be found in [this forum thread on Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2f120e62-52a9-4001-b8e0-15a897f28b7e/is-there-any-possible-to-create-a-local-account-on-domain-controller-not-domain-account?forum=winserverDS).

Comment: thanks Per-von, i hope you can also take a look at this thread below - http://serverfault.com/questions/728168/active-directory-domain-vs-dns-domain-are-they-the-same  - hope to hear from you.